# next.js custom server routing 404 error on deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My problem is on my next js app, on my contact submission form, it works on localhost but when I go to deploy it on ziet now, and go to use the form it get a 404 error returned.

```
const express = require("express");
const process = require("process");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const next = require("next");
var api_key = '--------------------------';
var domain = '---------------------------';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express();

        server.use(bodyParser.json());
        server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        server.post("/api/contact", (req, res) => {
            res.send(req.body);
            const name = req.body.name;
      const email = req.body.email;
      var interest = req.body.interest;
      const message = req.body.message;
```

I should be getting back a 200 message instead I get a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your routes on a centralized express server! A big no no. Zeit is all about a serverless future, so you should really define your routes in a now.json file and then put the logic for your endpoints in separate serverless lambda functions (1 lambda per endpoint is best).

It's tough to get your head around serverless at first, but there are some really cool advantages. Here's a great tutorial from Zeit to get your next.js/express app all set-up: https://zeit.co/guides/custom-next-js-server-to-routes